# incrementing and rendering text with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to do something pretty simple. Increment a number:

```
<div>
   <button v-on:click="increase">Add 1</button>
   <p>{{ sayHello() }} and {{ counter }}</p>
</div>
```

which will change an event here:

```
<b-form-input v-bind="renderText(counter)"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Type Alex"></b-form-input>
```

where this should just render whatever is in the text box.

```
<b-form-input v-bind="foo"
   type="text"
   placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>

 <p>Value: {{ foo }} and {{counter}}</p>
```

full code: but the only this that works in the `sayHello()` method.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form>
            <div>
                <button v-on:click="increase">Add 1</button>
                <p>{{ sayHello() }} and {{ counter }}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b-form-input v-bind="foo"
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>

        <b-form-input v-bind="renderText(counter)"
                   type="text" placeholder="Type Alex"></b-form-input> 
               <p>Value: {{ foo }} and {{counter}}</p>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import Vue from 'vue';


    export default Vue.extend({

        name: 'Hobbies',

        methods: {

            data:{
              foo: '',
              counter: 0
            },

            sayHello: function () {
                return 'Alex'
            },

            increase: function () {
                this.counter++;
            },
            renderText: function (event) {
                if (event == 5){
                    return 10
                } else{
                    return 16
                }
            }
        }

    });

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

when putting `data` outside of methods I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `data` inside `methods`, it should be at the root level, since we're in a component [it must also come as a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) :

```
export default {
  name: 'Hobbies',
  data: function(){
    return { foo: '', counter: 0 };
  },
  methods: {
    sayHello: function () { return 'Alex' },
    increase: function () { this.counter++; },
    renderText: function (event) {
      if (event == 5){
        return 10
      } else{
        return 16
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right I completely forgot that we were in a component, I edit this right away